# Best Java Collection to store key, value pairs and access its objects by Index or by key name

Tags: java, android, collections

I want to store a key,values pair that allows me to get the values by its position (ordering must persist) or by its key name. I was thinking to use HashMap but i do not want to iterate through all values to get the value by index.

I would need something like this:

```
MyCollection<String, Object> objects = new MyCollection<String, Object>();
objects.put ("id", Object1);
objects.put ("name", Object2);
// And now access the values by index:
Object obj1 = objects.get(1);
// or by key name:
Object obj2 = objects.getByKeyName("name");
```

What is the best collection to use (it must be android < 11 compatible>

Comment: Suggest you to use `LinkedHashMap` with [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13582099/1051509)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). It maintains the inserted order. You cannot get by index as they all implement the Map interface. You can do this way-

```
public List<String> getByIndex(final LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> myMap, final int index){
   return (List<String>)myMap.values().toArray()[index];
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively use toArray on the keySet to get by index:
Object obj1 = objects.keySet().toArray()[1];

Comment: @NickDK My edit and your comment crossed path in time. :) Thanks.