# "key-value" pairs collection maintaining order and retrieving by key and by pair index?

Tags: java, collections, tablemodel, abstracttablemodel

I'd would like to use a collection of "key - value" pairs:

- Which is the base for a [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) data model ([TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) implementation), so I need to access elements by their index/position (e.g. to implement `Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)`). The collection must preserve the order of the elements. An [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) would be good for that.
- Which allows to retrieve elements by the value of the key. A [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) would be good for that.

The closest usable collection I've found is [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). It preserves the order and allows retrieval by key. However the access to an item is not possible by index/position, I must iterate over the items until the good one is found. This is not be time-effective.

Is there a better one than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509391/how-to-get-the-one-entry-from-hashmap-without-iterating#1510023)? 
Thanks.

---

(Question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20285123/best-java-collection-to-store-key-value-pairs-and-access-its-objects-by-index-o), but the solution provided uses the conversion `toArray()` which is not time-effective. If the set of pairs changes, the conversion needs to be done again.)

Comment: try `SortedMap() || TreeMap()`.. or make custom class for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such collection implementation in the JRE.

But you can easily overcome this issue by using a `Map<K,V>` for storing the key-value pairs and an additional `List<K>` to store the keys in sequential order. You can then access a value either by key or by index using: `keyValueMap.get(keys.get(index))`.

You must make sure that modifications are always synchronized on both collections:

- Add/Change an entry: `if (keyValueMap.put(key, value) == null) keys.add(key)`
- Remove an entry: `if (keyValueMap.remove(key) != null) keys.remove(key)`

*Note that this implementation assumes that values are never `null`. In case `null` values are required too, the code gets slightly more complex as we have to check for existence of an entry using `keyValueMap.contains(key)`.*

Comment: Nice and easy. Thanks. Must be aware Map::put(k, v) also returns null when updating a previous entry where v was null, for implementations that allow null.

Comment: @mins you're right, null values are not supported here. I've added a note to my answer to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without implementing your own collection, it might be easiest to just have two collections, with the key-value reversed in the second one but otherwise ordered the same.

(wanted this to be a comment, but not enough rep yet)

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons Collection has a [ListOrderedMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/ListOrderedMap.html) class that makes what you want.

Comment: Appreciated, good to know. Thanks. May be the solution is using other classes from the package. For using only this one, I prefer to remain with the std API.