# Find keys that have at least n elements in common with another key, containing list

Tags: java, java-8, linkedhashmap

I have a `LinkedHashMap` of `<String, List<T>>`. I am building the Map, so maybe there is a better approach to organizing all the data.

I am trying to get the keys that have a common list, with at least 2 elements in common in each lists.

For example:

```
Map
----------------------
| Key | Values       |
----------------------
| M1  | [A1, A3]     |
| M2  | [A1, A2, A3] |
| M3  | [A1, A2]     |
| M4  | [A2, A3]     |
----------------------
```

In the end, I wish to have this list: `[ [M2, M3], [M2, M4], [M1, M2] ]`

- M2 and M3 contain both A1 and A2
- M2 and M4 contain both A2 and A3
- M1 and M2 contain both A1 and A3

I am stuck trying to figure out how to comparing the values of my first entry with the values of all the others. And so on, until I reach the end of my map (like a double `for` loop for a list).

My solution right now (but I definitely feel like there could be a better way)

```
List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<>(myMap.keySet());
for(int i = 0 ; i < keyList.size()-1 ; i++) {
    String keyA = keyList.get(i);
    List<T> valuesA = myMap.get(keyA);

    for(int j = 1 ; j < keyList.size() ; j++) {
        String keyB = keyList.get(j);
        List<T> valuesB = myMap.get(keyB);

        // compare both lists here
    }
}
```

Is using a Map the way to go?

Performance is not an issue for now. But it would be always be better to get something smoother

Comment: are these value any specific or random?

Comment: @ShubhamBhewanewala: How does it matter?

Comment: It will if values are of limited number

Comment: @ShubhamBhewanewala i'm so sorry. my computer crashed and left on vacation... Values are specific. I have a document where I have the x words in 1 article (words are Mx and articles are Ay). So for a selection of articles Ay, I have Mx. Or the other way around, I have Mx words that I'm searching in Ay articles (hope that makes sense)

Answer (score 1):

As I have noticed, you need `List<List<Output>>` which corresponds to the structure `[ [M2, M3], [M2, M4], [M1, M2] ]`.

Consider the very same input:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();      
map.put("M1", Arrays.asList("A1", "A3"));
map.put("M2", Arrays.asList("A1", "A2", "A3"));
map.put("M3", Arrays.asList("A1", "A2"));
map.put("M4", Arrays.asList("A2", "A3"));
```

Here is the working solution:

```
List<List<String>> output = new ArrayList<>();   // The output List
Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();              // Key storage used to avoid comparison                            
                                                 // of the keys twice (M1-M2, M2-M1)

for (Entry<String, List<String>> entryOuter: map.entrySet()) {               // First iteration
    if (keys.add(entryOuter.getKey())) {                                     // Adds a new key
        for (Entry<String, List<String>> entryInner: map.entrySet()) {       // Second iteration 
            if (!keys.contains(entryInner.getKey())) {                       // To compare?
                List<String> common = new ArrayList<>(entryOuter.getValue());
                common.retainAll(new ArrayList<>(entryInner.getValue()));    // The common items
                if (common.size() > 1) {                                     // At least 2 common?
                    output.add(Arrays.asList(
                        entryOuter.getKey(), entryInner.getKey()));          // Add these keys
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Calling `System.out.println(output);` prints the desired result:

> [[M1, M2], [M2, M3], [M2, M4]]

Briefly the idea described:

- The goal is to iterate each key with a different one only once - achieve 6 iterations.
- Use the `Set<String> keys` to store the "checked" keys.
- When a unique combination occurs, find the common values.
- If the number of common values is 2 or more, add the keys to the output `List` as a pair.
- Voilà, the task is done.

You have tagged [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) so I suggest you might want to use [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) which provides no real benefit here. [linkedhashmap](/questions/tagged/linkedhashmap) will not help you to iterate easier using indicies unless you implement a workaround: [How get value from LinkedHashMap based on index not on key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13581997/3764965)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach

1) Iterate value of each key in map (that will be a list)

2) Start another iteration from next index of above iteration till end

3) For each element in list of #1, use contains method to check if it is in the list of #2

```
a) Finish iterating list #3 as soon as two identical objects are found 

b) Iterate list in #3 till last but one if no element one

c) Iterate list in #3 till last if one element found
```

Hope that will help you

Comment: How do you assure to `"start another iteration from next index"` since no Map implementation allows to iterate using index at all? Do you mean: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13581997/3764965?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.  I've used String instead of Generic:

```
static Set<String> getCommonKeySet() {
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        Set<String> listOfKeysWithCommonValueSet = new HashSet<>();

        map.forEach((key, value) -> {
            map.entrySet().forEach(entry1 -> {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(value);
                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(entry1.getValue());
                list.retainAll(list1);
                if (list.size() >= 2)
                    listOfKeysWithCommonValueSet.add(key);
            });
        });
        return listOfKeysWithCommonValueSet;
    }
```

***EDIT:***

To return `Set<Set<String>>` use below code:

```
static Set<Set<String>> getCommonKeySet() {

    Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("M1", Arrays.asList("A1", "A3"));
    map.put("M2", Arrays.asList("A1", "A2", "A3"));
    map.put("M3", Arrays.asList("A1", "A2"));
    map.put("M4", Arrays.asList("A2", "A3"));
    //Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    Set<Set<String>> listOfKeysWithCommonValueSet = new HashSet<>();

    map.forEach((key, value) -> {
        map.entrySet().forEach(entry1 -> {
            if(!entry1.getKey().equals(key))
            {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(value);
                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(entry1.getValue());
                list.retainAll(list1);
                if (list.size() >= 2)
                {
                    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
                    set.add(key);
                    set.add(entry1.getKey());
                    listOfKeysWithCommonValueSet.add(set);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    System.out.println(listOfKeysWithCommonValueSet);
    return listOfKeysWithCommonValueSet;
}
```

***Output:***

> [[M1, M2], [M2, M3], [M2, M4]]

Comment: Even you use the OP's Map as an input the solution produces `[M1, M2, M3, M4]` as output which significantly differs from the OP's expectation `[ [M2, M3], [M2, M4], [M1, M2] ]`.

Comment: @Nikolas I just gave a hint, not a full solution. Anyway for that we need to use `Set<Set>`. I'll update it.

Comment: Still incorrect, produces `[[M1], [M2], [M3], [M4], [M1, M2], [M2, M3], [M2, M4]]
`. The inner part should be `if (set.size() > 1) {  listOfKeysWithCommonValueSet.add(set);  }`

Comment: @Nikolas right I need to skip the same keys :). It's not tested code. Thanks... I'll update it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea is to do the following steps:

1) The original input map.

```
+------+--------------+
| Keys | Values       |
+------+--------------+
| M1   | [A1, A3]     |
+------+--------------+
| M2   | [A1, A2, A3] |
+------+--------------+
| M3   | [A1, A2]     |
+------+--------------+
| M4   | [A2, A3]     |
+------+--------------+
```

2) Expanding the mapping in the following manner. Idea is to break the values into subsets so that we can group keys on the basis of values. eg: `[A1, A3]` present in both `M1` & `M2` represents `[A1, A3]` being common in both lists.

```
+------+--------------+-----------------------------+
| Keys | Values       |                             |
+------+--------------+-----------------------------+
| M1   | [A1, A3]     |                             |
+------+--------------+-----------------------------+
| M2   | [A1, A2, A3] | Expanding this entry        |
+------+--------------+ to create a mapping         +
| M2   | [A1, A2]     | of this key i.e. M2 with    |
+------+--------------+ all the possible            +
| M2   | [A1, A3]     | combinations of the         |
+------+--------------+ original value [A1, A2, A3] +
| M2   | [A2, A3]     |                             |
+------+--------------+-----------------------------+
| M3   | [A1, A2]     |                             |
+------+--------------+-----------------------------+
| M4   | [A2, A3]     |                             |
+------+--------------+-----------------------------+
```

3) Inverting the above mapping for doing groupBy on the new keys.

```
+--------------+--------+
| Keys         | Values |
+--------------+--------+
| [A1, A3]     | M1     |
+--------------+--------+
| [A1, A2, A3] | M2     |
+--------------+--------+
| [A1, A2]     | M2     |
+--------------+--------+
| [A1, A3]     | M2     |
+--------------+--------+
| [A2, A3]     | M2     |
+--------------+--------+
| [A1, A2]     | M3     |
+--------------+--------+
| [A2, A3]     | M4     |
+--------------+--------+
```

4) An inverted map with keys as the common elements & values as their corresponding keys.

```
+--------------+---------+
| Keys         | Values  |
+--------------+---------+
| [A1, A3]     | [M1,M2] |
+--------------+---------+
| [A1, A2, A3] | [M2]    |
+--------------+---------+
| [A1, A2]     | [M2,M3] |
+--------------+---------+
| [A2, A3]     | [M2,M4] |
+--------------+---------+
```

---

**Code:**

Then the following code creates the above mentioned inverted map in 4th step.

```
Map<List<Integer>, List<String>> invertedMap = inputMap.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(test::getAllCombinationsOfAList)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

where `test::getAllCombinationsOfAList` is(with [max 2^list_len iterations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/finding-all-subsets-of-a-given-set-in-java/)):

```
static Stream<Entry<ArrayList<Integer>, String>> getAllCombinationsOfAList(Entry<String,List<Integer>> set)
{
    int n = set.getValue().size();
    Builder<Entry<ArrayList<Integer>,String>> entryStream = Stream.builder();
    for (int i = 0; i < (1<<n); i++)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if ((i & (1 << j)) > 0)
                integers.add(set.getValue().get(j));
        }

        if(integers.size() >=2 ) {
            entryStream.accept(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(integers,set.getKey()));
        }

    }
    return entryStream.build();
}
```

Then the output of `res.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);` is:

```
[1, 2, 3]=[M2]
[2, 3]=[M2, M4]
[1, 2]=[M2, M3]
[1, 3]=[M1, M2]
```

Here, `key_list_length` represents the min number of elements which should be common for matching.

`value_list_length` >=2 represents that there is indeed a matching.

So a `key_list_length >= 2` & a `value_list_length >= 2` would be the desired output for you. eg:

```
Map<List<Integer>, List<String>> filteredMap = invertedMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().size() >=2 && e.getValue().size() >= 2)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,Entry::getValue));

filteredMap.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]=[M2, M3]
[2, 3]=[M2, M4]
[1, 3]=[M1, M2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Map<String, Set<T>>` rather than `List`. Then your own algorithm works like a charm.

```
Set<T> common = new HashSet<>(valuesA);
common.retainAll(valuesB);
if (common.size() > 1) ...
```

List would be usable for the map, or even `common` but is less efficient, less appropriate.