# How to fetch item from HashSet field property using Struts nested taglibs?

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, struts, hashset

I am trying to traverse an `ArrayList` and `Set` collection objects, using Struts nested tag. I have attached snippet of my code.

```
<snested:iterate property="productsList" id="aProduct">
   <snested:iterate property="participantList" id="participant_item">
       ......
     <snested:text property="firstName" styleClass="text"/>
  </snested:iterate>
</snested:iterate>
```

Here `participantList` is `Set` and `productsList` is `List`.
In above code I am getting following error:

```
Invalid argument looking up property: "productsList[0].participantList[0].firstName" of bean: "orderedProducts"
at org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.lookup(TagUtils.java:887
at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.BaseFieldTag.prepareValue(BaseFieldTag.java:126)
```

But If I use `List` instead of `Set` collection it works fine.

Comment: What is the object types?

Comment: ArrayList<Product> productsList;  and Class Product has a property named Set<ParticipantInfo> participantList and firstName is a property of ParticipantInfo Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is not an indexed collection. You can't use this class with the Struts nested tag.

If the requirement to use `Set` instead of `List` is mandatory then you should change the tag or tag library used this tag or use another tag library, i.e. JSTL, etc.

Comment: Is there any way to iterate over LinkedHashSet using struts nested taglib?

Comment: no, but you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31749969/573032) solution.